# Scroll Lock Equivalent In Word 2007/2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

In excel you can use the scroll lock key to toggle the arrow keys to move about the spreadsheet.  Can this be done in Word? If so, how?

Comment: I know it used to be possible in Word 6, 1993, I used to use it a lot. I'm still looking for it in current versions.